# Why doesn't my ng-hide work?

Tags: angularjs

Why doesn't my ng-hide on a failed json request?

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-hide="onError">
    Name: {{ user.name}}
    Location: {{ user.location}}
    Image: <img ng-src="{{user.avatar_url}}" />
        </div>
</div>

var MainController = function ($scope, $http) {

    var onUserComplete = function (response) {
        $scope.user = response.data;
    }

    var onError = function (reason) {
        $scope.error = "Could not fetch the user";
        return true;
    }

    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/robconery")
         .then(onUserComplete, onError);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change your `div` to instead hide when `$scope.error` is populated like so:

```
<div ng-hide="error">
```

Your `onError` function can remain as it is, but you don't need to return true. It can just populate `$scope.error` and your div will hide because `$scope.error` is truthy:

```
var onError = function (reason) {
    $scope.error = "Could not fetch the user";
}
```